# Adobe Flex file uploader

Tags: apache-flex, file-upload, flex3

I've been scouring the web to find a tutorial on how to implement a flex uploader, but didn't find any :(

Some tutorials just give the code and doesn't explain how to use them(sorry, i'm a newbie to flex)

can u geeks suggest some good tutorials? :)

thanks.

Comment: The Flex Reference Docs covers this pretty well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flex 888 has a few links](https://web.archive.org/web/20180919030916/http://www.flex888.com:80/296/9-flex-file-upload-examples-visited.html) for file uploading examples.  A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270863/displaying-progressbar-for-file-upload/2271001#2271001) was asked about this before, and answers provide good sources.

Here are two great examples of Flex file uploaders (using HTTP, referenced in that other SO question):

- [Flex File Uploader using PHP](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110111527/http://weblog.cahlan.com:80/files/FileUpload/FileUploadApp.html), [with source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108234937/http://weblog.cahlan.com:80/files/FileUpload/srcview/index.html).
- [Merb and Adobe AIR File Uploader](http://blog.vixiom.com/2007/06/29/merb-on-air-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload/), [with source](http://blog.vixiom.com/uploads/merb_air_upload.zip).

[image]
<sub>(source: [cahlan.com](http://codycodingcowboy.cahlan.com/uploaded_images/FileUpload-782091.jpg))</sub>

Let me know how it turns out.

Best,
Lance