# Laravel, best method, Ajax progressbar for files download

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache-flex, laravel

I'm building a Laravel4 website currently. With one main feat : downloading (updating) multiple files.
I'd like to display a progressBar (something simple as x% = (file n°)/(file total number), to ensure UX feedback for users.

Something already brainstormed @ [Displaying progressbar for file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270863/displaying-progressbar-for-file-upload)

Do you know a way to do this without Flex?
And what would the best one ?

Answer (score 1):

try to pass $_SESSION vars... inspired from {session.upload_progress}
http://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/

For instance, in your php *foreach* :

`$_SESSION['percentdownload'] = 95;//or any var e.g. $runningPercent;`

and run a JS loop which refresh the HTML/CSS progressBar periodically :

```
var xpercent = '@Session["percentdownload"]';
$("#myProgressElemId").updateFunction(xpercent);
```

But doing a JS loop is quite dirty ...

Actually you look for *pushing* updates.

---

ISNT it saner/safer to make oneByOne download ??
- 1st you query (Jquery get) the infos (number of files, names, sizes, etc)
- 2nd you *$.each()* (JQuery) and request download for each file... dumb ?